# Extracting the phase of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

Is it possible to extract the phase of a determinant without computing the full determinant?

More explictly, given a complex matrix $U$, the determinant can be written in the form 
\begin{equation}
\text{det}(U) = r e^{i\theta}.
\end{equation}
Is it possible to extract $\theta$ from $U$ without computing the full determinant?

**Edit :** As pointed by Hans Engler below, this can be done if we are happy with more work than computing the original determinant. I am looking for a method that is more efficient than computing the determinant itself.

Comment: Since computing a determinant involves both addition and multiplication this sounds *extremely* unlikely. But of course that would make it only more interesting when it turns out the answer is in fact yes. So against better judgement I'll wait here for some of the other posters to perform a miracle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Here is a way that is unfortunately a lot more work. Compute $W = (U^\ast)^{-1} U$. Then $\det W = e^{2i \theta}$.

You have found $\theta$ without computing $r$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you've guessed, I'm also interested in a method that is less work than the determinant itself. I will edit the question to add this condition.